# Modal won't pop up

Tags: php, html

If clicked : url:user_cart.php? (won't pop up) if i add # url:user_cart.php?# (it will pop up). I don't know why it happened because some of my pages are like this and it worked

```
                <tbody>
                    <?php

                    $dbhost = 'localhost';
                    $dbuser = 'root';
                    $dbpass = '';
                    $dbname = 'tradingdb';

                      $connection = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
                        if (!$connection) {
                          die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
                        }

                      $db_select = mysql_select_db($dbname,$connection);
                        if (!$db_select) {
                          die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
                        }

                          $query="select user_add_cart.id,user_add_cart.prod_cart_quantity,user_add_cart.total,product.prod_name,product.price from user_add_cart inner join product on product.id = user_add_cart.prod_id"; 

                          $result = mysql_query($query);
                          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
                          ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td hidden><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                        <td><a class='remove' href='#'><fa class='fa fa-close'></fa></a></td>
                        <td><a href='#'><img src='img/man/polo-shirt-1.png' alt='img'></a></td>
                        <td><a class='aa-cart-title' href='#'><?php echo $row["prod_name"];?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['price']?></td>
                        <td><a class='aa-cart-quantity' id="quant_value" name='quant'><?php echo $row['prod_cart_quantity']; ?></a></td>
                        <td id="totalprice"><?php echo $row['total'];?></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                  <button class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' href='#addquantity'>Edit</button> <!-- This is the button needs to be clicked to make modal pop up-->
                                </div>
                            </td>
                  </tr>
                            <?php 
                          }   
                          ?>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: If i put the button outside the table it will work.

Comment: You might want to show us the code that doesn't work? (I'm guessing you have some javascript laying around that's failing?). Checked the console for errors? Btw... outside the table = only one button and inside the table = multiple buttons? Correct? (it's in a loop)..

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. They are also insecure. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: i don't have. From my understanding all i have is that the table and the modal. it just won't work

Comment: Well, if you don't have any javascript, that's the problem! Modals arean't a html feature. If you don't know if you have any javascript, then we can't really help you (this forum is for short Q&A, not complete tutorials about what html and javascript is).

Comment: If i put the button outside of the table sir it worked. but there inside it wont. I just want to know why it will work if i add # in the url. Im just a complete beginner sir sorry

Comment: That's most likely your javascript that fails. Without seeing it, it's like walking in to a garage and asking them why your car (that you left at home) won't start. Unless they get to see it, they can't answer, right? It's the same thing...

Comment: Thank you for your comments sir.
I fixed it now.
I just delete that form tag >.< sorry im just too dumb